# how can i open right specified name tab from notification fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i am beginner developer android, i want my notification fragment leads to the correct name tab position
my parameter in rest val tab_approval_type:String
my parameter tab approval contains 3 parameter: overtime,leave,permit
and my tab contains 3 types included in one fragment, my name tab: overtime,leave,permit
i want this result example i click permit from notification fragment, then parameter show tab permit.
[image: now my notification after click not show right tab]

```
my code like this in fragment notification
private fun navigate(type: String) {
        if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.notificationFragment) {
            when (type) {
                "Approval" -> findNavController().navigate(NotificationFragmentDirections.navigateToApproval())
                
            }
        }
    }

how to fix this? thank you
```

Comment: need help thank u :)

Comment: In navigate() you have to pass the action to be performed. Check this https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate

Comment: can you give me example sir? i am newbie :O

Comment: If that other account is yours, you need to request an account merge via mod flag